# Newtonsoft.Json Deserialization only sets default values, incorrect data

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net, json-deserialization

I am loading JSON data in my Unity project via Newtonsoft JsonConvert.Deserialize. This works in Editor and the json is valid. However, as soon as I make a Windows build, the serialized data is empty / filled with default values instead.

This is also shown when I serialize the deserialized data and output it:

- Json string read:

```
    {
        "galleries": [{
            "id": "Acker",
            "title": "Auf dem Acker",
            "slides": [],
            "path": "/ChangeableContentData/Auf dem Acker",
            "showAllInFolder": true,
            "foldersRecursive": false,
            "enableSlideshow": false,
            "slideshowSlideDuration": 5.0
        }],
        "cardMenus": [],
        "urls": []
    }
```

- reserialized:

```
    {
        "galleries": [{
            "id": null,
            "title": "",
            "slides": null,
            "path": "",
            "showAllInFolder": true,
            "foldersRecursive": true,
            "enableSlideshow": false,
            "slideshowSlideDuration": 5.0
        }],
        "cardMenus": []
    }
```

Here is the relevant C# class:

```
    [System.Serializable]
    [Preserve]
    public partial class UIContentData
    {
        [JsonProperty("galleries")]
        public List<UIContentGalleryData> galleries { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("cardMenus")]
        public List<UIContentCardMenuData> cardMenus { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("urls")]
        public List<UIContentUrlData> urls { get; set; }
    
        public UIContentData() { }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    [Preserve]
    public partial class UIContentGalleryData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string title { get; set; } = ""; // optional
        [JsonProperty("slides")]
        public List<UIContentGallerySlide> slides { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("path")]
        public string baseFolderPath { get; set; } = "";
        [JsonProperty("showAllInFolder")]
        public bool showAllInFolder { get; set; } = true; // optional
        [JsonProperty("foldersRecursive")]
        public bool foldersRecursive { get; set; } = true; // optional
        [JsonProperty("enableSlideshow")]
        public bool enableSlideshow { get; set; } = false; // optional
        [JsonProperty("slideshowSlideDuration")]
        public float slideshowSlideDuration { get; set; } = 5f; // optional
    
        public UIContentGalleryData() { }
    }
```

Edit for clarity: I am using UIContentData object to deserialize.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UIContentData>(json);
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try not making them properties. Just public variables

Comment: @BugFinder there's no such thing as `public variables`. Using anything other than properties for .... properties is a major design bug too. Fields are implementation details even if they're public. All serializers work with properties by default

Comment: Well which ever term you choose. Funny how many cite do not work with get and set and actually they don’t just like they said

Comment: Like I said, it works when running the code from the UnityEditor, but not in the built project, so I am not sure what would be the difference there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Unity was stripping the class definitions I believe. Adding a link.xml with preserve="all" for the assembly containing them solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong class,should create one more. This code was tested and working properly

```
var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

public class Root
    {
        public List<UIContentGalleryData> galleries { get; set; }
        public List<object> cardMenus { get; set; }
        public List<object> urls { get; set; }
    }
```

and remove slides property from UIContentGallerySlide

```
[JsonProperty("slides")]
    public List<UIContentGallerySlide> slides { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am not using UIContentGalleryData for deserializing, I do have a root object and am using it for deserialization (otherwise I wouldn't get any list data at all)

Comment: @firala You don't have any data at all except defaults. Can you show us the class you are using

Comment: I added the UIContentData class for clarity in my post. The json data is valid and correctly formatted I believe, otherwise it wouldn't work in the Unity3d editor play mode either. It only stops working in the built files (Windows).

Comment: @firala Why are you waisting our time,if everything is working properly?  Why you then define a slides property  twice?

Comment: It is NOT working properly. I appreciate you trying to help, but can you at least read my comments properly?: "It only stops working in the built files (Windows)". I am trying to point out that the JSON is definitely valid and the code is working, it just fails to properly deserialize the "UIContentGalleryData" objects for the galleries list and once built to Windows standalone from Unity3d and I don't understand why.

Comment: @firala You  keep changing your question all the time, after having each new answer. Do you think it is looking good?  You  have to post the whole code. How do you obtain this json?

Comment: I am not changing the question at all. The json is read from a file, and it is read correctly, see the first block of code. Since I noticed the serialized data is filled with default values instead of the actual values, I serialize the object again and output it, see the second block of code. I have tried with different values, and multiple entries in the galleries array. It always reads the correct amount of entries (to avoid errors I am just using one right now), but all UIContentGalleryData objects are initialized with default values. Only happens in built app, not in the Unity Editor. why?